# Restyling the caption in an algorithm created with algorithm2e

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

In the caption of an algorithm created with `algorithm2e`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Caption.}
pseudocode
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

"Algorithm 1:" comes out bold. How could I change its font, say, to small caps?

Also, how could I make "Algorithm 1." appear instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `algorithm2e` package offers `\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator` to change the caption separator and `\AlCapFnt` to control the font for the label of the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{.}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont\scshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Caption.}
pseudocode
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've seen `\renewcommand{\AlCapSty}{\textsc}` used instead of `\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont\scshape}` (in this example). Do they do the same thing? Is one safer to use than the other?

Comment: @MSC `\renewcommand{\AlCapSty}{\textsc}` is wrong and it will produce errors, since `\textsc` expects an argument. Using the font switch `\scshape`, as in my answer, is the right way to do the redefinition.